# Flop count for variable initialization

Tags: time-complexity, flops

Consider the following pseudo code:

a <- [0,0,0]  (initializing a 3d vector to zeros)

b <- [0,0,0]  (initializing a 3d vector to zeros)

c <- a . b (Dot product of two vectors)

In the above pseudo code, what is the flop count (i.e. number floating point operations)?
More generally, what I want to know is whether initialization of variables counts towards the total floating point operations or not, when looking at an algorithm's complexity.

Comment: Well, no, but then if you decide to to use floating-point operations as a measure of complexity then it is of course up to you to determine that they are the limiting factor of the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, both `a` and `b` vectors are zeros and I don't think that it is a good idea to use zeros to describe or explain the flops operation.
I would say that given vector a with entries a1,a2 and a3, and also given vector b with entries b1, b2, b3. The dot product of the two vectors is equal to aTb that gives

```
aTb = a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3
```

Here we have 3 multiplication operations
`(i.e: a1*b1, a2*b2, a3*b3)` and 2 addition operations. In total we have 5 operations or 5 flops.
If we want to generalize this example for n dimensional vectors a_n and b_n, we would have n times multiplication operations and `n-1` times addition operations. In total we would end up with `n+n-1 = 2n-1` operations or flops.
I hope the example I used above gives you the intuition.